# Deserialize JSON to anonymous object using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

Im using JSON.NET do deserlaize an object, but i cant get it to work with the current structure of the object that im using.

http://dorobantu.me/post/2010/08/22/Deserializing-JSON-to-anonymous-types-in-C.aspx

My object currently looks liks this (i want to pass a list of objects)

```
[
{
    "ID": "Concurrent User",
    "FieldType": 190,
    "value": ""
},
{
    "ID": "System Type",
    "FieldType": 191,
    "value": null
}
]
```

Im getting the error:

```
Cannot deserialize JSON array into type '<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'.
```

What i need is something similar to example #2, a container object containing a list. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

c# code:

```
public void GetPoints()
    {
        string inputFields = HttpContext.Current.Request["inputFields"];

       // var test =  new { ID = string.Empty, FieldType = string.Empty, Description = string.Empty };

        var example = new { containerArray = new { ID = string.Empty, FieldType = string.Empty, Description = string.Empty } };

        var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(inputFields, example);
    }
```

javascript:

```
$('.quoteonly :input').live('change keyup', function () {

        var $container = $('#quoteonly-container');
        var containerObject = {};

        var containerArray = [];

        $container.find('.quoteonly :input').each(function () {

            var fieldType = $(this).data('fieldtype');
            var id = $(this).data('id');

            var currentObject = { 'ID': id, 'FieldType': fieldType };

            switch (fieldType) {

                case 190: //textbox
                    currentObject.value = $(this).val();
                    break;
                case 191: //select
                    currentObject.value = $(this).val();
                    break;
                case 192: //radio
                    currentObject.value = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case 193: //checkbox
                    currentObject.value = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
            }

            containerArray.push(currentObject);
            containerObject.containerArray = containerArray;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '../SentinelOperationsUI/GenericHandler.ashx',
            data: { 'FunctionName': 'GetPoints', 'inputFields': JSON.stringify(containerObject) },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Can you add some more code to get a contxt? The calling code and then the usage of the result

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- 1.

`var DTO = { 'items': JSON.stringify(containerObject) };`

```
$.ajax({
            url: '../SentinelOperationsUI/GenericHandler.ashx',
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

skip this step if in your code, you get the inputFields string like `{items: [{..}]}` and not like `[{..}, {..}]` I just added it for mu testing purpose. The important thing is to get a string inputFields in this format `[{..}, {..}]`

- 2.

.

```
 public void GetPoints()
        {
            string inputFields = HttpContext.Current.Request["items"];
            var test = new[] { new { ID = 0, FieldType = string.Empty, Description = string.Empty } };
            var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(inputFields, test);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a solution, cant test it now though. Didnt know about the `new[]` part. Thanks for helping!